# How do you determine if a curve in $\mathbb R^2$ is bounded?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Say you have a curve $D\colon y=x^2+1$. If I'm not wrong, $D$ is closed as it belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Is the curve bounded? If so, how do I determine if $D$ is bounded? And if it isn't, how can I prove that?

Comment: The points $(n,n^2+1) \in D$ so it cannot be bounded.

Comment: The curve $D$ is not a closed curve in $\mathbb R^2$. "It belongs to $\mathbb R^2$" does not tell you anything about the curve being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve can be parametrized as
$$
D = \{\, (t,t^2+1) \mid t\in\mathbb R\,\}.
$$
Hence, the norm squares of the points on $D$ are
$$
\|(t,t^2+1)\|^2 = t^2 + (t^2+1)^2.
$$
But $t^2+(t^2+1)^2$ is unbounded when $t\to\infty$, hence $D$ is unbounded.